# Homoclinic orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider an autonomous vector field on the plane having a hyperbolic
>   fixed point with a homoclinic orbit connecting the hyperbolic fixed
>   point. Can a trajectory starting at any point on the homoclinic orbit
>   reach the hyperbolic fixed point in a finite time?

I believe that by the definition of a homoclinic orbit that it cannot be reached in a finite time as $\phi(t)$ is a homoclinic orbit if $\psi(t) \rightarrow x_0$ as $t\rightarrow \pm\infty$ where $x'=f(x) $ at $x=x_0$. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: "orbit connecting the hyperbolic fixed point" Connecting this point to what? Please explain.

Comment: @Did Connecting hyperbolic fixed point to itself. Or you want the OP to say that?

Comment: @Evgeny I just wanted to know. Thanks. But yes, the OP should add this to the question.

Comment: I'd say that it's not important in this case whether orbit is homoclinic or not. For flows on real line there's a fact that for Lipschitz-continuous vector field it always takes infinite time for trajectory to reach the steady state. For reference you might use this http://books.google.ru/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&pg=PA37 . Arnold refers to this fact as to "comparison with linear ODE" and as far as I remember this could be generalized for multidimensional systems. I'm not 100% sure, though.